# How can run node-dev version 4.0.0 major js file?

Tags: node.js, express

I try to run last 2 years node.js express.js project file
its node-dev version is 4.0.0
When I run node-dev index.js
it show error (Module not found)
how can upgrade this project dependencies and how can run
Please help me
I am new to node.js
here is package.json

```html
"name": "m",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Marketing",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node-dev index.js"
  },
  "author": "ibEz",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "Faker": "^0.7.2",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "ejs": "^2.7.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.13",
    "mongoose-data-seed": "^2.1.3",
    "node-dev": "^4.0.0",
    "node-input-validator": "^4.0.1",
    "saslprep": "^1.0.3",
    "validation-error": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http": "0.0.0"
  },
  "mdSeed": {
    "seedersFolder": "./database/seeds"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by delete old package.json files and reinsatll all dependencies
Solved problem by myself.